# Adding minutes to end time appointment based on form input field

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, for-loop

I have a form to add some events to a calendar. I just need to set a begin time and next to itis a dropdown inputfield. Based on that value, I add some minutes to the begin time to set the end time of the event. Everything works, when an event goes over an our, the code breaks.

```
appointments = [
      {name: 'scheren', time: 30},
      {name: 'verven', time: 45},
      {name: 'knippen', time: 20}
    ]
    ;

    selectedValue: any;
    doSomething(data) {
     this.selectedValue = data;
     for (let i = 0; i < this.appointments.length; i++) {
     if( this.appointments[i].name == data){
        var setEnd =  this.beginTime.split(':');
        var hours = parseInt(setEnd[0]);
        var minutes = parseInt(setEnd[1]) ;
        if(minutes >= 30){

            var newHours = hours + 1;
            var newMinutes =  this.appointments[i].time;
            if(newMinutes < 10 ){
              var newtime = newHours + ':0' + newMinutes;
            }else{
              var newtime = newHours + ':' + newMinutes;
            }
        }
        else{

          var newMinutes =  minutes  + this.appointments[i].time;
        var newtime = hours + ':' + newMinutes;
        }
       return this.endTime =  newtime.toString() ;

     }

    }
```

So when a user sets the begin of an event to 13:45 and the event 'verven' takes 45 minutes the end time needs to be 14:30, but thats not working, everything above the last 30 minutes of a hour goes wrong. Is there some one who can help me fixing this?

Comment: why don't you use a date / time calculation function like moment?  saves you some headaches like these.

Comment: Do you have some example of that of a site where i can find some docs?

Comment: official docs provide a good start:   here's an example to get an idea of such functionality: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

Comment: Thanks for you help but i don't think this is the solution for me, i only have a begin time input field, no dates and while trying it seems that moment.js needs a date. Or am I wrong?

Comment: no you can use it for time only too.  also there are other libraries which do similar things.  you can do a search if you like.  In your case, even if you have to specify a bogus date to get it work, it doesn't matter.  you just take the hours of the calculation.  as you never have appointment overnight this would work.

Comment: You can also do it without a library, in a few simple steps. Add the event duration (minutes) from your event start meeting minutes. Example: 45 + 45 = 90. If the total is less than 60 simple addition is fine. If more like 90 then first use Math.floor(90/60) = 1 i.e. the hour to increment and then 90 % 60 = 30 i.e. the minutes to append. So your final time should be 14:30. You will also need to check if the hour increment is more than 24 in which case you can directly use the Math.floor() result.